# Storing specific values in a list by reading a file

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a file in the following format:

```
name | age | gender
abc  |  4  |  M
xyz  |  5  |  F
pqr  |  6  |  M
stu  |  5  |  F
```

It is a CSV file so name, age and gender are separate rows.

I am trying to store the values of age in a list and count the occurrence of similar ages.

Something like:

```
age_list = [4,5,6,5]
```

And the occurrence of each element.
I think I know how to do the occurrence part, what I cannot do is storing the values of age in a list.

I have only posted a small fragment of the file for clear understandings. The file is actually having huge amount of data.

I have only gotten to a point where I open the file in read mode and do something like:

```
data = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
```

I tried to search for a similar query but could not find it. I am new on this site so I do not really know the rules or guidelines.

Comment: If it's a CSV file, you should use the `csv` module.

Comment: As you yourself asked read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask (not that this was bad)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CSV format file and you want to use `csv` library:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('csvfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(data, None) # Ignore headers
    results = Counter([x[1] for x in data])
    print results
```

---

If you don't want to import `csv` and you have data in a string variable, this may help:

```
from collections import Counter

data = """name | age | gender
abc  |  4  |  M
xyz  |  5  |  F
pqr  |  6  |  M
stu  |  5  |  F"""

cleaned_data = Counter([x.split('|')[1].strip() for x in data.split('\n')[1:]])
print cleaned_data
```

**Output is the same for both examples:**

```
{
    '5': 2,
    '4': 1,
    '6': 1
}
```

Comment: Why need `Counter` here?

Comment: @KevinGuan `And the occurrence of each element`, READ.

Comment: 1. The OP stated that they did already import `csv`. 2. That `data` doesn't represent a CSV file at all. A CSV file's values are usually separated with commas.

Answer (score 0):

you can use csv reader or other libs like panda and numpy but if you want to use just python, this is the way! with no need to import anything extra

```
In [24]: ages = []
In [25]: with open("data.csv","r") as f:
   ....:     ages+=f.read().splitlines()
   ....:
In [26]: ages
Out[26]: ['name,age,gender', 'abc,4,M', 'xyz,5,F', 'pqr,6,M', 'stu,5,F']
In [27]: ages=[s.split(",")[1] for s in ages][1:] #all second cols(ages),except the first row
In [28]: ages
Out[28]: ['4', '5', '6', '5']
```